# FIWARE: GPS DATA ON CrateDB AND VISUALIZATION ON GRAFANA

Tags: gps, iot, grafana, cratedb

Actually, I am experimenting with FIWARE and IoT systems and I need to visualize on Grafana the localization of a specific device using a GPS. All data that GPS sends to Orion Context Broker (OCB) is latitude, longitude, altitude and they are in Cayenne LPP Format. My DataBase is based on CrateDB and QuantumLeap allows me to subscribe to changes in the OCB and copy them to the database

[The request from Insomnia is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzbW4.jpg)

For the beginning, I used the following post to subscribe the IoT LoRaWan Agent to the platform that supports this protocol (The Things Network Or ChirpStack)

After the subscription, the system automatically generates a table with data type float and only works with The Things Network, the problem is as soon as I add a second GPS device it is of type "String" instead of being of type "Object" so latitude, longitude, and altitude data do not appear.

Later, I used the data type "geo: point" instead of "float" and it is possible to record GPS data in CrateDB, because it is 2D location but the data is stored in String and Grafana cannot use this type of data Does anyone know what can be the ideal configuration?

*Note: CrateDB don't support 3D geolocalization just 2D geolocalization*

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!!**

I added a new object with a new two-variable (latitude and longitude) these ones are created based on the original variable gps_1 type ***geo_point***
[Solution create new object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0X8l.jpg)